# jmDNS ServiceListener triggers after being removed

Tags: java, android, jmdns

I used jmDNS to find some services on wifi network.
The problem is that sometimes after service is resolved, and I remove this listener, it triggers again with serviceResolved() method. jmDNS 3.4.1

```
private static JmDNS jmDNS;
private static ServiceType currentType;
private static ServiceListener currentListener;

public static Observable<String> getXXXIp(final ServiceType type,
                                             final WifiManager wifiManager) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override public void call(final Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

            InetAddress inetAddress = WifiUtils.getDeviceIpAddress(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo());

            try {
                jmDNS = JmDNS.create(inetAddress);
                currentType = type;
                currentListener = new ServiceListener() {
                    @Override public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) { ... }

                    @Override public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent event) { }

                    @Override public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) { ... }
                };
                jmDNS.addServiceListener(type.getCode(), currentListener);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while searching " + type.getCode(), e);
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    }).doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override public void call(String s) {
            finish();
        }
    }).doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private static void finish() {
    if (jmDNS != null) {
        LOGGER.info("jmDNS -> close");
        try {
            jmDNS.removeServiceListener(currentType.getCode(), currentListener);
            jmDNS.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot close jmDNS ", e);
        }
        jmDNS = null;
        currentListener = null;
    }
}
```

It is a little complicated logic of service check, so I cut it off, but the main thing that's matter is in one moment onNext() is called once so method finish() is called. And I checked hashcode for listener which I've nullified in finish() and when after this listener onServiceResolved() is called I check it hashcode and it is the same. What is going on? Any ideas?